# FindOneAndUpdate Subdocument Array In mongoose Removes Document Instead of updating

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

Hi Guys I need your help with the following code, I would like to update a subdocument in mongoose

Here is the code:

```
    const update = await Model.findOneAndUpdate({
  _id: id,
  "sponsors._id": sponsorId
}, {
  $set: {
    "sponsors.$": req.body
  }
}, {
  new: true
});

if (!update) {
  return next(
    new AppError("Something went wrong! Please try again later.", 400)
  );
}
```

However this code rather remove the subdocument and create a new one, I have gone through the documentation, which happen to be the correction way but I just don't understand why its rather removing instead of updating.

Please help

Comment: Can you show a sample document, sample `req.body` and what your expected result should look like?

Comment: the filed I would like to update is req.body.image

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MongoDB is replacing the subdocument because that is exactly what the update statement is telling it to do.

The positional operator `$` refers to the matching subdocument, the field name in the update `sponsors.$` is telling MongoDB to set the value of the matching subdocument to `req.body`.

To set a single field in that subdocument, use `sponsors.$.fieldname`.

If the fieldname is not known ahead of time, you might try building the update document dynamically.

```
updateDoc = {};
for (key in req.body)
{
   updateDoc["sponsors.$."+key] = req.body[key]
}
```

Then pass `updateDoc` to `$set` instead of `req.body`

Comment: Hi Joe, thanks for your response, it’s worked like a charm